# android build.gradle file for app - what is default repository

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, jcenter

In my build.gradle file for the top level build.gradle file - jcenter () is not specifically written.  so i have a the following in the top level build.gradle file:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
    }
}
```

somehow all my dependencies i have defined in my module are still found and the app runs fine. Can i assume that jcenter() is the default repo then if none is found ? is it used by default ? Otherwise how are my dependencies coming. Also if i wanted to over ride jcenter() to use another repo how would i do it.

so what if i had the following custom repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://someEnterpriseRepository.com/myRepo"
        }
    }
```

does that mean it checks maven custom repo first and then checks jcenter() if dependency is not found ?
BTW, i have cleared the IDE cache from file-->invalidate cache before testing all this.

Comment: Try running your build from the command line. My guess is that it will fail if you have no repositories defined. Certainly, that's what I am seeing. I cannot explain why the build works from within Android Studio, though.

Comment: After making this change, have you tried to change dependency - for example lower or higher version of any of library. This, what is important - this library, that you will add/lower/higher cannot be used before in any of your projects. As I remember in one of last update of AS - it is creating 1 common repository on your local computer for all projects, so if you download in 1 project, then it is available for all others

Comment: And are you sure, that it is till working for you? I have commented jcenter() in buildscript -> repositories and in allprojects -> repositories and I got errors during Sync

Comment: it could depend by the gradle cache (try to run gradle clean) and by your dependencies. Post also your build.gradle.
The gradle plugin can be cached.

Comment: Mateusz Pryczkowski i did what you asked and changed a version of a dependency and it did not compile so i guess your right its  a cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two reasons your build might work without a clearly stated repository in the script are:

1. Gradle uses [an init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) that defines a repository transparently.
2. The dependencies come from your local cache.

Comment: Your correct !! i checked the init.gradle script and it has the repo in it. Otherwise it would be a cache of sorts. Thanks.